# converting floating numbers in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a value in the database of type 'decimal(18,2)' , it has values like 2.50, 1.25 etc.. for some reason when i pull it in, it is not displayedm but all the other values of my table are.. I assume it is because I need some kind of conversion.. but not sure how to

```
 $_price = $row["_price"]; //suppose to pull in 2.50 for example
```

but comes in blank when i try to print it

```
print($_price_label.' '.$_price);
```

Comes out something like this  `'The value is $'` but the price is not pulled in..

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: This may sound awful, but are you using the correct column names for price? Also, try and var_dump $row to make sure the correct contents are there.

Comment: ayayay.. as aweful as it sounds this was the issue hahah i was using row[] instead of row2[]. Thank you

Comment: Thought so. I always hate to ask though. Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: @user710502 Cool, if it helped you, tell *slugonmission* to answer so you can accept and upvote him.

Comment: yes @slugnamission please do, and i will mark it

Comment: Why are you prefixing all your variables and (apparently) database columns with underscore?

Comment: no worries, i took care of all that @kristian thank you

Comment: Yeah @KristianAntonsen, the underscore prefix is _meant_ to be used for `private` and `protected` _class members_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert it, your variable is not set, or it is 0.

Check your variable names, keys, and column names.

If your column name is "price" you should be using `$_price = $row["price"];` (no underscore).